# Pandas check if two columns are the same

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = {'A':[3, 4, 5, np.nan, 6, 7],
        'B':[np.nan, 4, np.nan, np.nan, 6, 7]}
```

I have a data frame with two columns, A and B. I want to create a new column, C, which is the result of checking whether whether A and B are the same, if they are then keep it but if one is NaN, then keep the other value. Column A and B are always either a value or NaN. The values in A and B are always the same.

I know how to check whether A and B are the same:

```
df['C'] = (df['A'] == df['B]).astype('object')
```

But this gives a boolean answer in column C whether it's true or false. My expected output would be:

```
A   B   C
3  NaN  3
4   4   4
5  NaN  5
NaN NaN NaN
6   6   6
7   7   7
```

Comment: What is required when columns A and B have different value(s) i.e. not NaN and Not Equal?

Comment: Ah, yes - I'll edit the post, but they'll always be NaN or a value, the values will always be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `np.where()`

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[3, 4, 5, np.nan],'B':[np.nan,4,np.nan,np.nan]})
>>> df
     A    B
0  3.0  NaN
1  4.0  4.0
2  5.0  NaN
3  NaN  NaN

>>> df['C'] = np.where(df['A'].isna(), df['B'], df['A'])
>>> df
     A    B    C
0  3.0  NaN  3.0
1  4.0  4.0  4.0
2  5.0  NaN  5.0
3  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

**Edited Sample**

Showing that it would work if `df['A']` is nan and `df['B']` has value.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[3, np.nan, 5, np.nan],'B':[np.nan,4,np.nan,np.nan]})
>>> df
     A    B
0  3.0  NaN
1  NaN  4.0
2  5.0  NaN
3  NaN  NaN

>>> df['C'] = np.where(df['A'].isna(), df['B'], df['A'])
>>> df
     A    B    C
0  3.0  NaN  3.0
1  NaN  4.0  4.0
2  5.0  NaN  5.0
3  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Thanks :D

Comment: Tag it using `isna()`. Updating answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) where you can check multiple conditions.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[3, 4, 5, np.nan, 6, np.nan],
    'B':[np.nan, 4, np.nan, np.nan, 6, 7]})

df['c'] = np.select([df['A'].isnull() & df['B'].isnull(), df['A'].isnull()], 
                     [np.nan, df['B']], df['A'])
```

Output:

```
    A    B       c
0   3.0  NaN     3.0
1   4.0  4.0     4.0
2   5.0  NaN     5.0
3   NaN  NaN     NaN
4   6.0  6.0     6.0
5   NaN  7.0     7.0
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's guaranteed that A & B are identical values when not nans, then it looks like you could use `.combine_first` here:

```
df['C'] = df.A.combine_first(df.B)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `fillna` is sufficent for your requirement

```
df['C'] = df.A.fillna(df.B)

Out[92]:
     A    B    C
0  3.0  NaN  3.0
1  4.0  4.0  4.0
2  5.0  NaN  5.0
3  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  6.0  6.0  6.0
5  7.0  7.0  7.0
```